# Java - just recognise letters in a string

Tags: java, string, letter

I want to implement a program where a user can input any String and it appears just the letters at the console. If a String besides a letter is entered, the user should be informed about it. I've got some code so far but when I am entering for example "I-Love-You", "so much." the output should be "ILoveYou so much", but it actually does`t work like this because the output right now is "I-Love-You so much". Where is the mistake in my code?

```
// Input
int i = 0;
write("Please enter consecutively at least one word (only letters) and finish it with an empty one.");
String input = readString("Enter a word:");
while(input.length() == 0) { // Enter at least one word
    input = readString("Wrong input. Enter at least one word:");
}
while(input.length() != 0) { // End input by an empty String
    while(i < input.length()) { // Iterate through input
        char text = input.charAt(i);
        if(text >= 'a' && text <= 'z') { // Check lower case letters
            if(text >= 'A' && text >= 'Z') { // Check upper case letters
                if(text == 'ä' || text == 'ö' || text == 'ü' || text == 'ß'){ // Check mutated vowel
                    text = input.charAt(i-1); // Ignore wrong input
                    write("Wrong input.");
                }   
            }
        } 
    ++i;
}
String inPut = input +" ";
System.out.print(inPut);
input = readString("Enter a word:");
```

}

Comment: that looks over complicated, there should be a simpler way to do this.

Comment: I would be glad for a simpler method to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this following code, hope it would be helpful.

```
 int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter consecutively at least one word (only letters) and finish it with an empty one.");
    Scanner lire=new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = lire.nextLine();
    while(input.length() == 0) { // Enter at least one word
        System.out.println("Wrong input. Enter at least one word:");
        input = lire.nextLine();
    } 

    String output="";
    while(input.length() != 0){ 
        while(i < input.length()) { 
            char text = input.charAt(i);
            if( (text >= 'a' && text <= 'z') || ( text >= 'A' && text <= 'Z') || text == 'ä' || text == 'ö' || text == 'ü' || text == 'ß' || text==' ' ) { 
               output=output+text;
            } 

            ++i;
        } 
        System.out.println("Input : "+input);
        System.out.println("Output : "+output);
        System.out.println("Enter a word:");
        input = lire.nextLine();
    }
```

Output :

```
Please enter consecutively at least one word (only letters) and finish it with an empty one.
I-Love-you so much.
Input : I-Love-you so much.
Output : ILoveyou so much
Enter a word:
```

Comment: This looks actually very nice! But where can I inform the user that he entered a invalid string? Probably before the "++i;" right?

Comment: yes, you can add an **else** clause like so :  ` else{ System.out.println(" you have entred a wrong character :"+text);} `

Answer (score 1):

As it looks right now, you are setting an input from readString, but the loop isn't actually doing anything. text is set but never used. After exiting the while loop the initial value gets a space added and is printed, with no modification, that is why the original string comes out.

As for improving this, change the first while to an if statement, as that's what it's trying to do. Use a for loop to iterate through the string - even better, use an enhanced/for each loop:

```
for(char c : input) {
    // stuff here
}
```

It also looks like you are going to be calling the same method lots ending in a crazy stack of calls - instead if there is something wrong with the input you really want to start from the beginning of the function again. Hopefully that gives you a start

edit: an example

```
while(true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter consecutively at least one word (only letters) and finish it with an empty one.");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine();    
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    if (input.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter at least one word");
    }
    if (input.length() > 0) {
        for (char c : input) {
            // validate your characters
            result.append(c);
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());
        // optionally use return here to end the loop
    }
}
```

You could of course use string concatenation but StringBuilder is nice too. You'd just need to turn the character into a string (`Character.toString(c)`).
Notice that we are in an infinite loop with `while(true)`, and that if we have no words the loop will start from the beginning since we won't execute the second if statement.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, I try to consider this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into regular expressions. For example `.matches("[a-zA-Z]")` will match only letters.

```
String str = "I-Love-You so 234much'^Br7u..h.";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] arrr = str.toCharArray();
for (char c : arrr) {
    // I'm sure there's a way to include the space in the regex but I don't know how to
    if (String.valueOf(c).matches("[a-zA-Z]") || String.valueOf(c).matches(" ")) {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Output: `ILoveYou so muchBruh`

Comment: Thank you very much! I am not sure what you mean by regular expression? Is it connected to the Ascii table?

Comment: "A regular expression, regex or regexp is, in theoretical computer science and formal language theory, a sequence of characters that define a search pattern." First line from Wikipedia.
As I said, it's worth looking into, you can pretty much search for any pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the readString method to work, so I used regular expression instead. Hope this will help.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class wordSieve 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str;
        StringBuilder c = new StringBuilder();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter consecutively at least one word (only letters) and finish it with an empty one.");
        str = input.nextLine();

        while (str.length() != 0)
        {   
            // Find a to z or A to Z at least of length 1
            // maybe starting and ending with whitespace.
            regexChecker("\\s?[A-Za-z]\\s?{1,}", str, c);
            System.out.print("");
            str = input.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.print(c);
    }

    public static void regexChecker(String theRegex, String str2Check, StringBuilder outputStr) {
        Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(theRegex);
        Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher(str2Check);
        while (regexMatcher.find()) // find all the matches
        {
            if (regexMatcher.group().length() != 0)
            {
                outputStr.append(regexMatcher.group());
            }
        }
    }
}
```